# Container Not Scrolling Vertically In Safari

Tags: css, scroll, safari, overflow

I have a web page I'm building that has a flex container. Within the flex container there are 4 children elements that are cards that can be flipped when clicked. On the backside of the cards there is text that is supposed to scroll if there is overflow. I've got this to work on everything except for Safari. For some reason when I flip the cards and go to scroll in Safari the body scrolls instead of the container for the cards. The only format where the text overflows and scrolls is landscape mobile, so that's the only media query I included.

```js
const clicker1 = document.getElementsByClassName('card')[0];
const clicker2 = document.getElementsByClassName('card')[1];
const clicker3 = document.getElementsByClassName('card')[2];
const clicker4 = document.getElementsByClassName('card')[3];

clicker1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clicker1.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
});

clicker2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clicker2.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
});

clicker3.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clicker3.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
});

clicker4.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clicker4.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
});
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 638px) {
  body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(39, 39, 39);
  }
  .card-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 90%;
    min-height: 0px;
    height: 90%;
    perspective: 1200px;
  }
  .card {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    min-height: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    margin: 1%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 15px;
    -webkit-transition: transform 2s;
    transition: transform 2s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    /*-webkit-transform: ;*/
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .card:hover {}
  .card.is-flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  .card-face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  .card-front-face {
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: lightgray;
  }
  div .image {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 45%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 45%;
  }
  div h2 {
    position: relative;
    top: -7%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  }
  div h5 {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -21%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-style: italic;
  }
  .card-back-face {
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex: 1 1;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 5%;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  .card-description {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  }
   ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
  }
   ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgb(136, 136, 136);
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
   ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: rgb(22, 22, 22);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-face card-front-face">
        <img class="image" src="Portfolio Project Pictures/Growth Image.jpg" />
        <h2>GROWTH</h2>
        <h5 class="flip-icon">Click To Flip</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-face card-back-face">
        <p class="card-description">
          I'm looking to consistently grow as a developer. I don't see getting a job in this industry as the finish line. In an ever changing industry I don't think a finish line truly exists, constant learning and adapting is required. I want to be able to acquire
          more knowledge everyday so that I can get to a point where I can see the big picture of situations and learn how to apply knowledge on the fly without having to turn to other people or the internet.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-face card-front-face">
        <img class="image" src="Portfolio Project Pictures/Remote Working 
                    Image.jpg" />
        <h2>REMOTE</h2>
        <h5 class="flip-icon">Click To Flip</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-face card-back-face">
        <p class="card-description">
          One of the biggest appeals to me with web design is the common ability to be able to work remotely. The idea of location independence really appeals to me. I understand that for some companies they would like their new developers to be on-site for a while
          before going remote. I totally understand and am willing to compromise with that, but ultimately I would like to eventually go fully remote once mutual comfort with that work set-up is built.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-face card-front-face">
        <img class="image" src="Portfolio Project Pictures/Meaning Image.jpg" />
        <h2>MEANING</h2>
        <h5 class="flip-icon">Click To Flip</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-face card-back-face">
        <p class="card-description">
          Meaning is something that is super important to me. Working at a job just simply for the sake of working at a job is not something I can do long term. There has to be some type of bigger purpose that is a part of the job. Technology has been something
          that has completely revolutionized the world. I'd like to be part of that and help businesses and individuals alike.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-face card-front-face">
        <img class="image" src="Portfolio Project Pictures/Balancing 
                    Image.jpg" />
        <h2>BALANCE</h2>
        <h5 class="flip-icon">Click To Flip</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-face card-back-face">
        <p class="card-description">
          When I come to work I work hard and give it my whole focus. However, in complete transparency, with finally entering into this career field after years of hard work to get here I do want time to be able to enjoy it. I think a good work/life balance is
          very important to productivity at the workplace. Don't worry, I definitely expect more work than play and will not be requesting 15 hour work weeks.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="Goals.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet so that the card flipping works.

Comment: Are you referring to the inability to scroll in the cards when the mouse is placed in it?

Comment: No, it's when it's in landscape mode on mobile that I can't scroll it with my finger @カメロン